# How to get JMX connection in JBoss fuse

Tags: jboss, activemq-classic, jmx, jbossfuse, simplejmx

Im try to get JMX connection from JBoss fuse, to count number of pending messages in ActiveMQ but im not able to get JMX connection. It always ends with exception

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi://0.0.0.0:44444/jndi/rmi://0.0.0.0:1099/karaf-root");
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
```

Exception below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected String[2], got null
    at org.apache.karaf.management.JaasAuthenticator.authenticate(JaasAuthenticator.java:46)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl.doNewClient(RMIServerImpl.java:232)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl.newClient(RMIServerImpl.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub.newClient(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.getConnection(RMIConnector.java:2430)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:308)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing required credentials.

Looking at [this tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/lmalventosa/entry/jmx_authentication_authorization) you need to provide credentials to the `JMXConnectorFactory`

```
Map env = ...;
String[] creds = {"monitorRole", "mrpasswd"};
env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);
JMXConnector cc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, env);
```

Comment: @Herman glad it helped you. Please accept my answer (the tick on the left side), thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi://0.0.0.0:44444/jndi/rmi://0.0.0.0:1099/karaf-root");

HashMap<String, String[]> environment = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
String[] creds = { "admin", "admin" };
environment.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);

JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, environment);
MBeanServerConnection connection = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
```